# Action Bar Sherlock doesn't keep transparency when orientation is changed from portrait to landscape

Tags: android

I'm using Android Sherlock in one project where I show a VideoView. When the screen orientation is portrait, the video and some text is shown. When is landscape, only the video in fullscreen is shown.

Well, my doubt is: why the alpha color (of the Sherlock Action Bar) is shown when the orientation is portrait, but changes it's alpha property (becames opaque) when the orientation is landscape?

My onCreate() is showed below:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Makes action bar become translucent, and sets layout of this activity.
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);
}
```

Well, I'm using **requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY)**, which allows the alpha color in the action bar.

When the orientation changes, I call onConfigurationChanged(), which calls setScreenLayout(). This method sets the video size and change the action bar background color.

```
/**
 * Sets the screen layout, according with the current orientation.
 * 
 * @param isInLandscapeMode
 */
public void setScreenLayout(Boolean isInLandscapeMode) {
    // If orientation is landscape.
    if (isInLandscapeMode) {
        // Hides text of the layout.
        mTextScrollView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // Set the size of the video.
        setVideoDimensions((int)Math.floor(mWindowWidth * (1 / WIDESCREEN_RATIO)), mWindowWidth);
        // Sets window to full screen.
        setWindowToFullScreen();
        // Sets action bar background color.
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.bg_translucent_black));
    }
    // If orientation is portrait.
    else {
        // Shows text of the layout.
        mTextScrollView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        // Set the size of the video.
        setVideoDimensions(mWindowWidth, (int)Math.floor(mWindowWidth * WIDESCREEN_RATIO));
        // Sets window to normal screen.
        setWindowToNormalScreen();
        // Sets action bar background color.
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.bg_translucent_black));
    }
}
```

This color is set in res/colors.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="bg_translucent_black">#11EEEEEE</color>
</resources>
```

In my AndroidManifest.xml, I set the VideoActivity with the **android:configChanges="orientation"** property, which allows the video to continue playing if the orientation is changed.

```
<!-- Video Activity -->
<activity 
    android:name=".VideoActivity" 
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
/>
```

Therefore, when the orientation is changed, the onCreate() isn't call.

I think what is happening is that the **requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY)** allows the alpha only in the first orientation when the activity is created (in this case, in portrait). This way, the landscape orientation doesn't became alpha color. But I'm not sure.

What I'm sure is that I need the alpha color of the action bar in both orientations.

Anybody knows if is possible for my video to have alpha color in both orientations?

Answer (score 0):

I believe ActionBarSherlock needs Android to handle the configuration changes, and not your app. Using the android:configChanges "hack" and ActionBarSherlock together in one app isn't possible.

Comment: Well, so how can I have two different alpha color in my Action Bar, for both orientations of my video?

Comment: Get the orientation of the device in the onCreate of your Activity, and set the alpha color of your ActionBar dynamically that way.

Comment: The default orientation of my video activity must be portrait. So, I won't get the orientation. I'll just get it after the video starts (when the flip could be done).
The matter is that the alpha isn't working (and I need two different alpha's for each orientation while the video is playing).
The alpha works only after onCreate() being called. But in this activity I'm using **android:configChanges="orientation"** in the AndroidManifest, which prevents the onCreate() to be called when the orientation changes.

Comment: I need the same behavior of the youtube app (in portrait mode the action bar is translucent and in landscape also, but fullscreen).
In ICS this flip pauses the video and then restarts in the new orientation (from where it stopped). In my app I can't use this process because it must run in API's 7 to 10, which has slower processing. Many times this process (pause video, flip cel, restart video) causes delay into the video.
My only alternative is to change the action bar alpha when the cel flips, which isn't working.

Comment: To get the same behavior as the youtube app, you can't use configChanges="orientation". ActionBarSherlock relies on this to redraw it's Views. It's either you take out the configChanges hack, or you don't use ActionBarSherlock.